# Reusing ViewModel between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-viewmodel

I am using Navigation Component to write an app that is one activity multiple fragment architecture and passing the data(class object) by using ShareViewModel. My issue is passing data between fragment works fine, however when I back to the previous fragment the data change to the latest object store in ShareViewModel.

> The flow would be like:
>
> `characterListFragment` -> `characterDetailFragmentA` -> `episodeFragment` -> `characterDetailFragmentB`
>
> Start to back navigation:
>
> `characterDetailFragmentB` -> `episodeFragment` -> `characterDetailFragmentA` (The shown data is same as the `characterDetailFragmentB` one) -> `characterListFragment`

Here is my navGraph:  ​

1. `characterListFragment`which show a list of data.
2. `characterDetailFragment`which show the selected data from characterListFragment.
3. `episodeFragment` which show the all the data in selected episode.
   [image]

I am using a shareViewModel to pass data between `characterListFragment` and `characterDetailFragment`. Also I reuse the shareViewModel to pass data between `episodeFragment` and `characterDetailFragment`

Here is the shareViewModel code

```kotlin
class ShareSelectedCharacterViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Character>()

    fun select(item: Character) {
        selected.value = item
    }
}
```

And I hook the shareViewModel to the activity lifecycle like so

```kotlin
private val shareViewModel: ShareSelectedCharacterViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

When I selected a data in `characterDetailFragment` or `episodeFragment` I will set the data to shareViewModel and get the data in `characterDetailFragment` by using the same lifecycle scope shareViewModel.

```kotlin
// Set selected data
shareViewModel.select(character)
 
sharedModel.selected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { 
        // Observe the data
})
```

My issue is passing data between fragment works fine, however when I back to the previous fragment the data change to the latest object store in ShareViewModel. I know the data will be change due to the using the same viewModel. So I am wonder is there any way to handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve this problem. Adding a stack structure in  `ShareViewModel` and detect the back navigation in `characterDetailFragment` .

```kotlin
/**
 * Using stack to store the sharedData and pop the stored data
 * when user pressBack.
 */
class ShareSelectedCharacterViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val stack = Stack<Character>()
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Character>()

    fun select(item: Character) {
        selected.value = item
        stack.add(item)
    }

    fun pop() {
        stack.pop()
        if(stack.isNotEmpty()) {
            selected.value = stack.peek()
        }

    }
}
```

When I press back button in `characterDetailFragment`  I call the `viewModel.pop` method to set the previous data into `selected`.

```kotlin
         /**
         *   Implement Custom Back Navigation:
         *   when user pressBack in CharacterDetailFragment, we also need to pop out the data
         *   that stored in the ShareSelectedCharacterViewModel to retrieve previous one.
         */
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            findNavController().popBackStack()
            sharedModel.pop()
        }
```

Is there a better way to handle this situation?